# What is the maximum size we can give for nvarchar in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, nvarchar, max-size

In SqlServer we can use NVarchar(MAX) but this is not possible in sqlite. What is the maximum size I can give for Nvarchar(?)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no maximum in SQLite.  You can insert strings of unlimited length (subject to memory and disk space.)  The size in the `CREATE TABLE` statement is ignored anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes it is accepting any big number. I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: There is, however, a global maximum string/blob length which defaults to 1,000,000,000 bytes (http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

Comment: On windows phone, using SQL Lite, the max is 4000. If you need bigger, then you can use ntext (though i believe this is being deprecated and may not be in future versions).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the maximum size I can give for Nvarchar(?)?

You don't, because Sqlite will ignore anything over `255` when specified inside `NVARCHAR(?)`.

Instead, use the `TEXT` datatype wherever you need `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

For instance, if you need a very large string column to store Base64 string values for images, you can use something like the following for that column definition.

```
LogoBase64String TEXT NULL,
```

SQLite doesn't really enforce length restrictions on length of string.

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type
>   name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not
>   impose any length restrictions (other than the large global
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

Source [www.sqlite.org/datatype3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)